# I've created a chrome app, and I want to give it a link form the desktop (launchbar, startmenu, etc')

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I've created a chrome app. This app runs as a panel (in an app mode in a separate window, not as a tab), and the only way I see that I can launch the application is through the new tab (that might be different at times if user installed some new tab replacement extension).

Is there any way to do so? I obviously would prefer for this to be automatic, but using a manual fix could be considered, at least to get some things going...

Here's the manifest I'm using:

```
{
    "name": "My App",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*",
        "clipboardWrite"
    ],
    "icons": {
    "128": "static/icon/128.png",
    "16": "static/icon/16.png"
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version": "4.1",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "view/main.html",
            "container": "panel"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [instruction](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710) how to manually make app shortcuts.